# QMenu is crossing the parent window frame?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qtembedded

[image: QMenu example]
I am using QtEmbedded-4.8 for my development project. A typical problem I am facing, is with the behavior of QWidgets.

I have used QMenu API for handling with menu. Problem is when a particular multilevel menu is opened, sometimes it is crossing the frame of the parent window.This thing should not happen in case of my project. I want the menu widget being displayed within the frame of parent window all time....

How to resolve this issue?

[image: QMenu when opened in multilevel structure]

Comment: What are your target platforms? Why is this behavior unwanted? Can you please make a screenshot?

Comment: Target platform is Linux.....

Comment: You have to write your own menu, by inheriting from QMenu and adjust menu behaviour in paintEvent function